# unable to connect azure resources to log analytics

Tags: azure-log-analytics, oms

I am trying to connect azure web applications to web apps using azure portal.
I navigated to "Azure resources" in the section "work space data sources" from menu bar.
And choosen web app from the list in the same resource group, and selected PT1M and click on save.

When i click on save, it shows me the error as below
Failed to update connection settings for resource to Log Analytics.

Any Suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue. Go to your Azure subscription, under the resource provider blade, make sure that microsoft.insights provider is registered. If not, register and then try again.